# Rails update column in controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, crud

I have this user model

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  attr_accessible :email, :name, :password_hash, :password_salt, :secret, :surname, :code, :updated_by
  attr_accessible :password, :password_confirmation
  attr_accessor :password
  attr_protected :secret

  before_save :encrypt_password

  validates_presence_of :name
  validates_presence_of :email
  validates_uniqueness_of :email
  validates_confirmation_of :password
  validates_presence_of :password, :on => :create

  def encrypt_password
    if password.present?
      self.password_salt = BCrypt::Engine.generate_salt
      self.password_hash = BCrypt::Engine.hash_secret(password, password_salt)
    end
  end

  def self.generate_code
      Array.new(32){Random.new.rand(36).to_s(36)}.join
  end

... etc
end
```

and in front controller im doing this

```
def code_generation 
    @user = User.find(:first, :conditions => {:email => params[:email]})
    if @user
      @user.code = User.generate_code
      @user.save # HERE .SAVE IS RETURNING FALSE, SO I DONT HAVE IT IN DATABASE
    end
end
```

The problem is @user.save return false and code is not changed in database, what im doing wrong ? thank you.

edit: this line `@user.code = User.generate_code` work, i can check it via debug.

Comment: Check `@user.errors` after the save fails. It will likely tell you what's wrong.

Comment: Thank you thats it, there were error in lenght of one column.